# Why does using a function to generate random numbers lead to a slower quicksort?

Tags: c++, sorting, quicksort

I want to generate `1000000` random numbers,and use quick sort algorithm to sort them.There are two different programs:

```
// Program 1
void quicksort()
{
   // ...
}

int main()
{
    int *arr = new int[1000000];

    // generate random number in main()
    std::default_random_engine e(100);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned> u(1,10000);
    for(int i = 0;i < 999999;++i)
       arr[i] = u(e);

    clock_t start = clock();
    quicksort(arr,0,999999);
    clock_t end = clock();
    cout<<"time:"<<static_cast<float>(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<endl;
    delete [] arr;
    return 0;
}
```

Output: `time:0.361684`

```
// Program 2
void quicksort()
{
       // ...
}

void generateRandom(int *arr,int size,int seed)
{
   std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned> u(0,1000);
   std::default_random_engine e(seed);
   for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
       arr[i] = u(e);
}

int main()
{
        int *arr = new int[1000000];

        generateRandom(arr,1000000,100);  // The only different between Program1 and Program2

        clock_t start = clock();
        quicksort(arr,0,999999);
        clock_t end = clock();
        cout<<"time:"<<static_cast<float>(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<endl;
        delete [] arr;
        return 0;
}
```

Output: `time: 1.88307`
Why use `generateRandom()` to generate random numbers lead to quick sort slower?[Here](https://gist.github.com/renyuntao/bff19880b2b5276bed3c) is the complete program.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just noticing that there is a small difference between both programs at std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned> u(0,1000); . Not that this would solve it.

Comment: There are slight differences in the code which leads me to believe the code you actually ran may contain other differences.

Comment: @immibis He-Man's Father's brother's second cousin's former roommate. Ren is this repeatable? If the sample size is 1 this could just be the generated numbers just didn't sort as well, the antivirus held off a small invasion force, or the OS scheduled another task to run part way through.

Comment: Can you repro this in ideone or some other online compiler?

Comment: you generate different test datasets, one is ranged 0->1000 the other is ranged 0->10000 maybe this contributes to the difference

Comment: Is there a reason you're not initializing the last element of the array?

Comment: @pm100 Thank you very much,you are right,when I modify 0->1000 to 0->10000,the problem is gone.But I am not understand  it,can you explain why?

Comment: Possibly increased duplication. Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339227/quick-sort-algorithm-improvement-if-more-duplicate-keys

Comment: @Ren - I added an answer that solves the issue using a different pivot and partition scheme. In your example code, there's a minor error,  | for(int i = 0;i < 999999;++i) | arr[i] = u(e); | should be | for(int i = 0;i <= 999999;++i) | arr[i] = u(e); | or | for(int i = 0;i < 1000000;++i) | arr[i] = u(e); |

Comment: @rcgldr - Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are clocking only the call to quicksort, which would isolate the time difference to only the work of sorting the already-generated numbers.

The runtime of quicksort varies based on its input. Quicksort runs in `O(n**2)` in the worst case. `O(n log n)` on average. For instance, if a quicksort implementation were to select the first available element as pivot, then the worst case scenario would be to give it an already-sorted array because more swaps would be needed.

You are getting differences in timings because your inputs are different, not because you are generating the numbers in a function vs inline. Your generator uses the same seed in both programs, but you are using a different distribution (1,1000) vs (1,10000) -- which will lead to a completely different set of ints.

A smaller spread in your uniform distribution will reduce entropy in your array (e.g., there will be more duplicate values), which will affect the number of swaps you have to do to get the array sorted completely. The initial relative ordering in your array will affect how many times integers will have to shift around your chosen pivots.

The layout of your generated numbers in memory is the same in both cases (one linear array), and the program's footprint is small enough that we can safely rule out code cache misses as causing a difference in runtime inside the quicksort call. Your total runtime will be affected by the number of memory compares and swaps you're doing (and the few cache misses you're incurring -- you have 4MiB of numbers to sort, it isn't much). I assume the code in both `quicksort()`s is the same.

Edit:

To illustrate the problem, you can modify your program as follows:

```c
for(int i = 0;i < 999999;++i)
  arr[i] = i; //u(e);
```

to drop the random generation altogether. this makes your quicksort algorithm work on an already sorted array -- and it is a worst case.

On my system, trying a few runs of the version where the numbers are generated inside a function completes within 1 to 2 seconds (as it is show in the external code link), whereas using the sorted version completes in a far longer amount of time. Sorting an already-sorted array of numbers from 0 to 100000 (instead of one million) alone takes over 15 seconds.

(edit: both stable/unstable algorithms are affected by duplicates. thanks @rcgldr )

Comment: Is a 5x difference in timing really likely with random data?

Comment: When I modify 0->1000 to 0->10000,the problem is gone.But I am not understand it,why different data set will cause different run time?

Comment: The amount of work varies based on the input. O(n^^2) worst case, O(n log n) on average.

Comment: 1M*1M/(1M*lg 1M)=1M/lg 1M=~50k meaning that 5 times difference in performance is small compared to the worst case scenario.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the partition method used in the linked to example. It's using a Lomuto like partition scheme, instead of a [Hoare partition scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme). I tested using Visual C / C++ express 2010 release build, and the results were even worse, 0.1 second for 1->10000, 2.7 seconds for 1->100.

In the example code below, I used a Hoare partition scheme combined with a median of three for pivot, and the time improves with more duplicates or ordered data.

On my system, Intel 2600K, 3.4ghz, using Visual C / C++ express 2010 release build, sorting 10,000,000 integers. This variation of quicksort took 0.531 seconds with distribution 1->10000, 0.469 with 1->1000, 0.375 with 1->100, and 0.109 with already sorted data. clock() is based on 64hz ticker, so times +/- 0.015625 seconds.

```
typedef int int32_t;

void quicksort(int32_t a[], int lo, int hi) {
    int i = lo, j = (lo + hi)/2, k = hi;
    int32_t pivot;
    if (a[k] < a[i])            // median of 3
        std::swap(a[k], a[i]);
    if (a[j] < a[i])
        std::swap(a[j], a[i]);
    if (a[k] < a[j])
        std::swap(a[k], a[j]);
    pivot = a[j];
    while (i <= k) {            // partition
        while (a[i] < pivot)
            i++;
        while (a[k] > pivot)
            k--;
        if (i <= k) {
            std::swap(a[i], a[k]);
            i++;
            k--;
        }
    }
    if (lo < k)                 // recurse
        quicksort(a, lo, k);
    if (i < hi)
        quicksort(a, i, hi);
}
```